# What are the Pre-processing steps required before Object annotation in Deep learning using Keras ?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am new in deep learning. What are the pre-processing steps I should use before annotating my object.
I have an Dataset of images of size 640*360. I want to continuously detect this object in an video in any background.
Like should I crop the object and then annot ? Or should I Use the Entire Image and annot the specific Object ?

[Which Image should Be considered for annotation ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rkq5.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

So you have mentioned two ways you can go.

1. Like should I crop the object and then annot ?

Yes. This is a an easy option. after cropping you should be able to use a sliding windows technique to search in test images. But bear in mind that this process is quite expensive.

You should take a look the paper called R-CNN. Its methodology is quite similar.
Paper link: https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Girshick_Rich_Feature_Hierarchies_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf?spm=5176.100239.blogcont55892.8.pm8zm1&file=Girshick_Rich_Feature_Hierarchies_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf

2. should I Use the Entire Image and annot the specific Object ?

This is the more recent way to go where you allow the model to learn itself what the subject is and where it is located in the given image. Usually you will have a image and the annotations like [x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, height, width] for each objects. The model should be trained to produce those outputs as close as possible.

For multiple objects you will need a layer called ROI-pooling layer. This is explained in https://deepsense.ai/region-of-interest-pooling-explained/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may I ask why this answer is down voted ?